# Android, SQLlite misinterprets "value" to be a column (field)

Tags: android, sqlite

Hope someone more knowledgable on the use of SQLlite on Android is able to provide a helpful remark to this "quiz", thanks beforehand:

A simple table is created

```
String CREATE_DIRBLE_COUNTRIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + DIRBLE_COUNTRIES_TABLE
    + "("
    + COLUMN_DUMMY + " TEXT,"
    + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY,"
    + COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT,"
    + COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT,"
    + COLUMN_SLUG + " TEXT,"
    + COLUMN_ANCESTRY + " TEXT,"
    + COLUMN_COUNTRYCODE + " TEXT,"
    + COLUMN_REGION + " TEXT,"
    + COLUMN_SUBREGION + " TEXT"
    + ")";

db.execSQL (CREATE_DIRBLE_COUNTRIES_TABLE);
```

This table is then to be checked for duplicates, thus:

```
String Query = "Select * from " + table + " where " + column + "=" + value;
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, null);
```

This results in an exception:

> Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Belarus (code 1): , while compiling: Select * from countries where name=Belarus

What is causing SQLlite to interpret the value Belarus in the column name as a column?

In an almost identical table of "genres", with COLUMN_ID used as primary key, this code works perfectly. This is why I replaced the COLUMN_ID with a dummy in case it caused a conflict with the _ID column that supposedly is created automatically.

Comment: My advice, as rude as it may seem (stressed), is that you need to learn the basics of SQL (not specific to SQLite).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

String literals in SQL go in `'single quotes'` to not be interpreted as identifiers such as column names.

However, it's even better to use `?` variables and bind the values:

```
String Query = "Select * from " + table + " where " + column + "=?";
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Query, new String[] { value });
```

Comment: Working. Would you please add a short explanation why it is better to bind the values?

Comment: @carl For example you don't have to escape `'` characters in values.

Answer (score 1):

change your code line

```
"Select * from " + table + " where " + column + "=" + value;
```

to

```
"Select * from " + table + " where " + column + "= '" + value+"'";
```

value should be in single quote.